# Two Angular projects - different configurations

Tags: angular-cli, angular9

I have two Angular 0 projects. I am trying moving some code from project1 to project2. The code that works in project1 is not working in project2. While researching the problem I am comparing projects configuration. So,

project1:

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.1
Node: 10.15.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.0.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.900.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.900.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.900.1
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.1
@angular/cli                      9.0.1
@angular/flex-layout              9.0.0-beta.29
@ngtools/webpack                  9.0.1
@schematics/angular               9.0.1
@schematics/update                0.900.1
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.41.2
```

As you notice it doesn't have Router package although the router works fine.

project2:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.1
Node: 10.15.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.2
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular       0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr    0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer     0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack       0.901.1
@angular-devkit/core                9.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics          9.1.1
@angular/animations                 9.0.7
@angular/cdk                        9.2.1
@angular/cli                        9.1.1
@angular/flex-layout                9.0.0-beta.29
@angular/forms                      9.0.7
@angular/language-service           9.0.7
@angular/material                   9.2.1
@angular/platform-browser           9.0.7
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   9.0.7
@angular/router                     9.0.7
@ngtools/webpack                    9.1.1
@schematics/angular                 9.1.1
@schematics/update                  0.901.1
ng-packagr                          9.1.1
rxjs                                6.5.5
typescript                          3.7.5
webpack                             4.42.0
```

Second project does have a router package.

My question is: does it make any difference in terms of Router configuration?

Thanks

Update.
I have the following code in project1:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
<a mat-tab-link
  *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
  [routerLink]="link.link"
  routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
  [active]="rla.isActive">{{link.label}}
</a>
</nav>
```

Which works fine, but in project2 I am getting errors:

```
    ERROR in projects/prism/src/app/top-navigation/top-navigation-component/top-navigation-component.html:4:5 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.

4     [routerLink]="link.link"
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  projects/prism/src/app/top-navigation/top-navigation-component/top-navigation-component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './top-navigation-component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component TopNavigationComponent.
projects/prism/src/app/top-navigation/top-navigation-component/top-navigation-component.html:6:5 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'active' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.

6     [active]="rla.isActive">{{link.label}}
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  projects/prism/src/app/top-navigation/top-navigation-component/top-navigation-component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './top-navigation-component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component TopNavigationComponent.
projects/prism/src/app/top-navigation/top-navigation-component/top-navigation-component.html:5:28 - error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'routerLinkActive'.

5     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  projects/prism/src/app/top-navigation/top-navigation-component/top-navigation-component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './top-navigation-component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component TopNavigationComponent.
```

Project1. Module component:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from './../../shared/shared.module';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  declarations: [ SettingsComponent ]
})

export class SettingsModule { }
```

Comment: Could you share the information, what exactly is not working in project2?

Comment: Added more code

Comment: Is `RouterModule` imported (I mean added to the `imports`) in every `@NgModule()` where the components use the router in the project2? (`routerLink` is part of the `RouterModule`.)

Comment: Yes, import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

Comment: But in the module is it in the `imports` array also? It is not enough to import it with `import { Router, RouterModule} from '@angular/router'`

Comment: I am not sure about that. I am adding module configuration for project1.

Comment: Every Angular module, that uses the router has to add the RouterModule to its `imports` array in the module configuration. Otherwise the components of the module will be not able to use the elements of the `RouterModule`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just added the module configuration. Project2 has exact the same module. What interesting is when I move the mouse over routerLink with ctrl down in the template of project1 it gives context info, it's not happening in the project2.

Comment: Another detail is that sometimes it gives these errors during ng serve, but sometimes it ng serve compiled successfully and the errors show in a few seconds.